# Adding model-wide help text to a django model's admin form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

In my django app, I would like to be able to add customized help text to the admin change form for some of my models.  Note I'm not talking about the field specific `help_text` attribute that I can set on individual fields.  For example, at the top of the change form for `My_Model` in `My_App` I'd like to be able to add some HTML that says "For additional information about My Model, see http://example.com" in order to provide a link to an internal documentation wiki.

Is there any simple way of accomplishing this, or do I need to create a custom admin form for the model?  If so, can you give me an example of how I would do that?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There is a fairly simple, yet underdocumented way of accomplishing this.

### Define render_change_form in the Admin class

First, you need to pass extra context to your admin. To do this, you can define a render_change_form function within your admin Class, e.g.:

```
# admin.py
class CustomAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def render_change_form(self, request, context, *args, **kwargs):
        # here we define a custom template
        self.change_form_template = 'admin/myapp/change_form_help_text.html'
        extra = {
            'help_text': "This is a help message. Good luck filling out the form."
        }
        
        context.update(extra)
        return super().render_change_form(request, context, *args, **kwargs)
```

### Creating a custom template

Next, you need to create that custom template (change_form_help_text.html) and extend the default 'admin/change_form.html'.

```
# change_form_help_text.html
{% extends 'admin/change_form.html' %}
{% block form_top %} 
    {% if help_text %}<p>{{ help_text }}</p>{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I've chosen to place this template inside templates/admin/myapp/, but this is also flexible.

---

More info available at:

http://davidmburke.com/2010/05/24/django-hack-adding-extra-data-to-admin-interface/

http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/NewformsHOWTO#Q:HowcanIpassextracontextvariablesintomyaddandchangeviews

Comment: I think "underdocumented" is being generous.  Good catch.

Answer (score 80):

Use the admin's [fieldsets](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets):

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('first', 'second', 'etc'),
            'description': "This is a set of fields group into a fieldset."
        }),
    )
    # Other admin settings go here...
```

You can have multiple fieldsets in an admin.  Each can have its own title (replace the `None` above with the title).  You can also add `'classes': ('collapse',),` to a fieldset to have it start out collapsed (the `wide` class makes the data fields wider, and other class names mean whatever your CSS says they do).

Be careful: the `description` string is considered **safe**, so don't put any uncleaned data in there.  This is done so you can put markup in there as needed (like your link), however, block formatting (like `<ul>` lists) will probably look wrong.

Comment: IMHO it depends on if fieldsets are acceptable to your application. If they are, use my answer; if not, use Andre's.

Comment: This answer is exact I want, almost use a extra form field to just show a help link on Change Page. I finally use `... 'description': format_html(f'<a href=...>helper link</a>)} ...`

Answer (score 3):

Besides the possibility of creating [fieldsets with descriptions](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets) you can [override the admin's template for the change form](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates).

Comment: I was writing that one up as well, but it got out of hand fast.  The problem isn't overriding the admin templates, it's getting the additional per-model info from the model to the template, which looks like you'd have to override the admin *view* or use a context processor.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you want the code below should do what you want.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ClassName, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if siteA:
            help_text = "foo"
        else:
            help_text = "bar"
        self.form.fields["field_name"].help_text = help_text
```

That's an example of using some logic to modify an overriden form. So you just put this in your ModelAdmin constructor that you overrode.

Comment: I'll just add this method is for overriding the form

Answer (score -3):

Just as an update to this question. You can do this in the model using `help_text`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.help_text

Comment: That's for one field, and he specifically pointed out in the question that he wasn't talking about that.

Answer (score -3):

Since django 3.0 it's now possible to override the `help_text` of admin fields more easily:

```py
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class AuthorForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ('name', 'title', 'birth_date')
        labels = {
            'name': _('Writer'),
        }
        help_texts = {
            'name': _('Some useful help text.'),
        }
        error_messages = {
            'name': {
                'max_length': _("This writer's name is too long."),
            },
        }
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields

Comment: Did you even read the question?